how to share hash() function output with multiprocessing.Array in python 3?
I need to share some 64-bit integers in a python 3 multiprocessing runtime.
I tried to use multiprocessing.Array, and it works on linux, but fails on Windows.
The long type for multiprocessing.Array is 64-bit on linux, but on Windows (10) it's only 32-bit! Cannot use the same code on both OSes.
Are there other options if I don't want to manipulate pointers with multiprocessing.RawArray?
(P.S. Cannot use multiprocessing.Manager)

A long long (type code 'q' or 'Q') is 64 bits on both platforms, I believe.

pretty sure python3 handles ints > 32bits regardless of OS , can show explicit examples where this is not the case  - copy/paste code from both platforms . there's also ctypes longlong ....
